# Getting MKMapRect from MKTileOverlayPath

Tags: ios, mapkit

I searched a lot for an answer & I can't imagine that such method is not existing!!
I've an MKTileOverlayPath (x , y & z) and also was able to get lon/lat of the center of this rectangle.
Now I need to get span of each rect, is that possible?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, though it's not entirely obvious with only MapKit.

Tiles & overlay paths are defined in a grid system where the number of points on a side of the (square) map equals `2^z * 256` since the default screen tile size is `256px` square. `z0` is one `256px` square tile, `z1` is four tiles for a total world of `512px` square, etc. Tile coordinates in this system are linear (all squares in a square map).

`MKMapPoint` is derived from `z20` such that `MKMapSizeWorld` is `268,435,456` map points on a side. If you do the math, `2^20 * 256 = 268,435,456`. Map points are also linear (pixels/points in a square map).

Latitude and longitude of course is not linear since this is a projected representation which is why you have functions like `MKMetersPerMapPointAtLatitude()`.

If you have the following `MKTileOverlayPath`:

- `z = 10`
- `x = 12`
- `y = 8`

You know that the world point size is `2^10 * 256 = 262,144` and that the world is `2^10 = 1,024` tiles on a side.

The tile's left edge is `256 * 12 = 3,072` points in and the top edge is `256 * 8 = 2,048` points down. These are in relation to `z10`, which is `268,435,456 / 262,144 = 1,024` times smaller scale than `z20`.

This is an `MKMapPoint` of `{ x: (3,072 * 1,024 = 3,145,728), y: (2,048 * 1,024 = 2,097,152) }`.

The bottom right is similarly `{ x: 3,407,872, y: 2,359,296 }` (add the tile's size of `256 * 1,024 = 262,144` to each).

You can use `MKCoordinateForMapPoint()` on each to get `CLLocationCoordinate2D` out, as well as subtract their differences to get the `MKCoordinateSpan`.

- Top left: `{ latitude: 84.8024737243345, longitude: -175.78125 }`
- Bottom right: `{ latitude: 84.7705283207591, longitude: -175.4296875 }`
- Span: `{ latitudeDelta: 0.0319454035754205, longitudeDelta: 0.3515625 }`

Yes, these points are very close to the top-left Alaska region of the map, but that's logical given that `x = 12` and `y = 8` out of `1,024` tiles numbered from the top left.

```
@interface GridTileOverlay : MKTileOverlay

@end

@implementation GridTileOverlay
-(void)loadTileAtPath:(MKTileOverlayPath)path result:(void (^)(NSData *, NSError *))result {
    NSLog(@"Loading tile x/y/z: %ld/%ld/%ld",(long)path.x,(long)path.y,(long)path.z);

    int worldPointSize = pow(2,(int)path.z)*256; // 2^10 * 256 = 262,144
    int tilesOnASide = pow(2,(int)path.z);       // 2^10 = 1,024
    long leftEdge = path.x *256;                 // 256 * 12 = 3,072 points
    long topEdge = path.y *256;                  // 256 * 8  = 2,048
    int w = self.boundingMapRect.size.width;     // 2^20 * 256 = 268,435,456
    int zScale =  w / worldPointSize;            // 268,435,456 / 262,144 = 1,024
    int tileSize = 256 * zScale;                 // 256 * 1,024 = 262,144
    long x0 = leftEdge*zScale;                   // 3,072 * 1,024 = 3,145,728
    long y0 = topEdge*zScale;                    // 2,048 * 1,024 = 3,145,728
    long x1 = x0 + tileSize;
    long y1 = y0 + tileSize;

    MKMapPoint ul = MKMapPointMake(x0, y0);      // upper left
    MKMapPoint lr = MKMapPointMake(x1, y1);      // lower right
    MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectMake (fmin(ul.x, lr.x),
                              fmin(ul.y, lr.y),
                              fabs(ul.x - lr.x),
                              fabs(ul.y - lr.y));
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

variations on a theme

```
  + (MKMapRect)mapRectForTilePath:(MKTileOverlayPath)path
{
    CGFloat xScale = (double)path.x / [self worldTileWidthForZoomLevel:path.z];
    CGFloat yScale = (double)path.y / [self worldTileWidthForZoomLevel:path.z];
    MKMapRect world = MKMapRectWorld;
    return MKMapRectMake(world.size.width * xScale,
                         world.size.height * yScale,
                         world.size.width / [self worldTileWidthForZoomLevel:path.z],
                         world.size.height / [self worldTileWidthForZoomLevel:path.z]);
}

/*
 Determine the number of tiles wide *or tall* the world is, at the given zoomLevel.
 (In the Spherical Mercator projection, the poles are cut off so that the resulting 2D map is "square".)
 */
+ (NSUInteger)worldTileWidthForZoomLevel:(NSUInteger)zoomLevel
{
    return (NSUInteger)(pow(2,zoomLevel));
}
```